# What's the best way to handle Arabic language (right-to-left) on Storyboards?

Tags: ios, ios7, localization, uistoryboard, right-to-left

My situation is that languages that are left-to-right fits well on my UIStoryboard with some minor tweaks; that's no problem.

But I don't know how to handle languages that are right-to-left. Are we supposed to have different Storyboards for these languages? Since these languages are from right-to-left the alignment of labels and buttons should be right-aligned I guess.

What's the best way to deal with these languages?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, yes, you use RTL settings for RTL languages. Do you have trouble doing this so far? Explain the problem please.

Comment: What do you mean by RTL settings? I'm still in the process of localizing and don't have the localized strings yet but started to get concern about how to handle RTLs in case if I have to go the separate UIStoryboards route.

Comment: OK. I get your question now. I meant the alignment and so on. I haven't worked with localization for RTL & LTR languages together, so I'm afraid I'm not sure about the answer, one thing I know, it's always painful to deal with RTL in Xcode!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to once work on an app with multiple localized storyboard, and this was a mess. The problem is, instead of 1 storyboard to modify if something is wrong, you got multiple. Two times the job is bad...

When I was confronted to the same problem again (but I wasn't using storyboard), i dealed with it by detecting the phone language and applying differents options regarding the language :

```
+ (BOOL)isDeviceLocalizationFrench{
    NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    return [language rangeOfString:@"fr"].location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Then make your label "seen" in your controllers by making IBOUlets, and modify the text alignment for thoses labels according to the language. This might seems a long process at first, but it's not as hard has managing multiple storyboard on the long term.

Comment: Having sphagetti code to tackle this is also a mess. Couldn't imagine the testing effort that's needed when you change something drastic. Also, having multiple Storyboards may not be ideal either for me as I have some 30+ UIViews on the Storyboard. God, I wish there is a better solution to deal with this. Localization, looks to me, is not that easy.

Comment: If you want to go even further, you could use a custom UILabel subclass that change every NSTextAlignmentLeft to NSTextAlignmentRight depending on the language. The logic would be only at one place, you would just have to change your UILabel to your custom class